# clickable link with cancel button instead of hover

Tags: html, css

The below code is popping up a table when we hover the mouse on the text. Instead can we make it clickable and then pops up a table with a cancel button at the top right (so that when we click on cancel, the table disappears).

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <table id="t1">
      <tr>
        <th id="q">Quon</th>
        <th id="q1">SE</th>
        <th id="q2">SE</th>
        <th id="q3">SE</th>
        <th id="q4">SETY</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="df3">
        <th id="i1">Ict</th>
        <td id="i2">as</td>
        <td id="i3">ds</td>
        <td id="i4">fd</td>
        <td id="i5" rowspan="2">dfd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th id="j1">Juion</th>
        <td id="j2">How</td>
        <td id="j3">How</td>
        <td id="j4">How</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will help you - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Comment: I wouldnt use w3school. This is also one of the outdated topics. The modern approach is to use `.classList.toggle('class-name')` instead of `.style`

Comment: Thanks..But Can we hava cancel button at the top right? so that when we click on it, it closes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to add a `<button>` for closing. I positioned it fixed at the top right of the screen.
2. You need to add a class to display element such as `.d-block` and use within CSS: `display: block;`
3. You need to add the `onclick` attribtue to fire a script to the button and the element `.dropdown`
4. To show an element you use `document.querySelector('.class-name or #id or tagName').classList.add('d-block');`
5. To hide an element, you use the same function just use `.remove` instead of `.add`

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.close-btn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  right: 10px;
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="close-btn" onclick="document.querySelector('.dropdown-content').classList.remove('d-block'); document.querySelector('.close-btn').classList.remove('d-block');">Click to close</button>
<div class="dropdown" onclick="document.querySelector('.dropdown-content').classList.add('d-block'); document.querySelector('.close-btn').classList.add('d-block');">
  <span>Click me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <table id="t1">
      <tr>
        <th id="q">Quon</th>
        <th id="q1">SE</th>
        <th id="q2">SE</th>
        <th id="q3">SE</th>
        <th id="q4">SETY</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="df3">
        <th id="i1">Ict</th>
        <td id="i2">as</td>
        <td id="i3">ds</td>
        <td id="i4">fd</td>
        <td id="i5" rowspan="2">dfd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th id="j1">Juion</th>
        <td id="j2">How</td>
        <td id="j3">How</td>
        <td id="j4">How</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. One last question:) Can we have "Click to close" inside the table only :) ??

Comment: of course then you need to wrap the close button and table isnide the same relative parent and position it absolute.

Comment: Can you please help me here

Answer (score 3):

This is the easyest way to make something like this in JavaScript:

```js
function show() {
  document.getElementById("show_this").style.display = "block";
}

function hide() {
  document.getElementById("show_this").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show()">Show</button>
<div id="show_this" style="display:none;">
  <button onclick="hide()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

(You just need to add `onclick="show()"` and `onclick="hide()"` attributes to your tags.

Comment: You should avoid to use `.style` function in JS in 2021. The modern approach is to use `.classList` +
 `.add('class-name')` , `.remove('class-name')` or `.toggle('class-name')` to apply changes through CSS.
 This causes far less issues incl. possible specificity weight issues.

Comment: Thanks. But where I can place a table here? Sorry I am new to html and css

Comment: I'll create an example for you